# SSRS column chart has very skinny columns

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

SSRS 2012, I have a column chart with a single series that looks decent in the designer. [image]
BUT when I Run... and view the chart, the columns are very skinny.  I'd like the columns to appear just like the designer, where the width goes right up to the next value. [image]

- Both the x/y axis are SQL Server int
- Horizontal Axis > Properties >Axis Options > Interval Type=Number,
  Interval = 1
- Series > Custom Attributes > Point Width = 1, and manipulating
  [Min|Max]PixelPointWidth has no effect.

Comments with blind links will be mocked with child-like glee.

Thanks.
Jim

Comment: =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031331/ssrs-column-chart-has-very-skinny-columns

Comment: Does it change if you make your chart wider? It might be due to the formula used to calculate the size of the bars and spaces. It can freak out when there are more than 15 or so bars.

Comment: You said the x axis values are integers, but are you sure about that? Look at the placement of the bars, if those were integer values they would align with the x axis interval markers (which are set to increments of 1). It looks to me like they are actually decimal or float data instead, which could be one reason for gaps between the bars. Anyway, one thing you can try is select the y-axis chart series and then edit the property General > CustomAttributes > PointWidth and try increasing it to 1

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely due to the paramteres (if any) or the size of the calcualtions. What you can do alternatively if change the Dynamic Size (Height, Width) of the Chart (located in chart propoerties). However, you will have to test it out to ensure it is properlly formated on the page. [image]